# Return data for two columns from two tables and perform a calculation on them with stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

A mini employee accounts system, I have two tables, the employees_salaries table and the allowance table, each one has a column of employee_id To connect them.

I want to return the value in the basic_salary column from employees_salaries table
and return the value in the allowance_value column from allowance table
and make sum operation on them and insert the result into Net_salary column in employees_salaries table.

i want to make that with Stored Procedure Sql server .

[image: Digram For DataBase tables]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a **Scalar Function** and return the allowance amount from the allowance table

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetValue(@EmpID INT)
RETURNS INT
AS 
SELECT allowance_value
FROM [allowance table]
WHERE E_ID = @EmpID
```

And then Alter the Employees Salary table & add a new Column

By passing the EmployeeId, you Can get the data

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.employees_salaries 
ADD NewColumnName AS (dbo.GetValue(employees_salaries.[EmpId Column]) + employees_salaries.[Basic pay Col])
```